# Authorize with OAuth2 for Youtube API

Tags: python, youtube-api

I have recently written a Telegram bot in Python which gets the latest video from my YouTube channel and posts it to my related Telegram channel. For that I only need to authorize the YouTube request to get the latest video with an API key. So far so good.

However, today I thought it would be useful if a new video is retrieved is also added to a playlist. For this API endpoint I need to use OAuth2 (which is new to me).

As I understand it, I can make invoke [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube%27) with a PUT request providing the Bearer OAuth2 token. However, I am not sure to provide the secret in this way.

I have the following function:

```
def addLatestVideoToPlayList(oauth2: str, 
secret: str, playlistId: str, videoId: str):
    uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
    requests.put(uri, params={"Authorization": f"Bearer {oauth2}"})

    uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems'

    response = requests.post(uri, json={
        "snippet": {
            "playlistId": playlistId,
            "resourceId": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": videoId
            }
        }
    })

    print(response.json())
```

I am a bit confused, from looking at the API documentation, there is another way to invoke the authorization API with a POST request, but it is unclear to me where to pass the token and where to pass the secret.

Any pointers would be great. Please excuse the naive question.
Thank you.